# Split a list and add remainder evenly to other sublists in Python

Tags: python, list, split

Lets say I have a list of:

```
['apples','oranges','bananas','pineapples','grapes','mushrooms','milk']
```

How would I split this into lists of `n` items each (in my example `3` items per sublist) and have whatever the remainder added evenly to as many sublist as possible?

My first solution would be to split each group into the amount of I want, take the last list and then depending on it's size add it to each first group but I'd be hardcoding the values..

I don't even know how to start thinking this logically.

EDIT:

Result:

```
[['apples','oranges','bananas','milk'],['pineapples','grapes','mushrooms']]
```

Comment: So ... What is your desired result?

Comment: What is the expected result for the given list? `['apples','oranges','bananas']`, `['pineapples','grapes']`  and `['mushrooms', 'milk']` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

```
a = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'pineapples', 'grapes', 'mushrooms', 'milk']
n = 3 # No of groups
[a[i::3] for i in range(n)]
```

Output

```
[['apples', 'pineapples', 'milk'], ['oranges', 'grapes'], ['bananas', 'mushrooms']]
```

Comment: This reorders the list... `['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas',...` becomes `['apples', 'pineapples', 'milk']`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
li=['apples','oranges','bananas','pineapples','grapes','mushrooms','milk']

n=3
for chunk in [li[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(li), n)]:
    print chunk
```

Prints:

```
['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']
['pineapples', 'grapes', 'mushrooms']
['milk']
```

Or you could do something along these lines:

```
def partition(lst, n):
    ''' divide lst in n nearly even size chunks '''
    n=min(len(lst),n)
    q, r = divmod(len(lst), n)
    indices = [q*i + min(i, r) for i in xrange(n+1)]
    return [lst[indices[i]:indices[i+1]] for i in xrange(n)]    

for n in range(1,5): 
    print n, partition(li, len(li)/n+1)
```

Prints:

```
1 [['apples'], ['oranges'], ['bananas'], ['pineapples'], ['grapes'], ['mushrooms'], ['milk']]
2 [['apples', 'oranges'], ['bananas', 'pineapples'], ['grapes', 'mushrooms'], ['milk']]
3 [['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'], ['pineapples', 'grapes'], ['mushrooms', 'milk']]
4 [['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'pineapples'], ['grapes', 'mushrooms', 'milk']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

lst = ['apples','oranges','bananas','pineapples','grapes','mushrooms','milk']
new_lst = []
sets = 2

if len(lst)/sets > 0 :
    iterate = math.floor(len(lst)/sets)
else:
    iterate = math.ceil(len(lst)/sets)

for x in range(iterate):
    new_lst.append([])
    for y in range(sets):
        new_lst[-1].append(lst.pop(0))

for x in range(len(lst)):
    new_lst[0].append(lst.pop(0))


print(new_lst)
```